# System with multiple inputs, but when one is activated it disables the other inputs

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I am currently working on a bank system. However, it cannot accept multiple inputs at the same time (through multiple ATMs). So I made it so that every ATM will output a signal when a user has activated it. This signal needs to go to a redstone system that I need and don't know how to make compactly (Thus the question). Here is what this system needs to do:

1. Receive multiple inputs (around 20 ATMs)
2. Can be easily tiled next to each other so it can be expanded to more possible inputs (not necessary if it is not possible)
3. When a pulse is detected in one input, it should deactivate the others while outputting a constant signal signal maintained by a hopper clock. (Refer to #4 -#6 for more detail)
4. When the hopper clock counts down, it should reset all the inputs so all the ATMs should be able to send a input through. (Basically resetting the system so other ATMs can contact it).
5. The hopper clock should also output a constant signal that can be taken from the system until it is done counting.
6. The hopper clock should last around 8 stacks of regular item's time when counting.

I have tried to make this system but it's a mess that I guarantee will fail. So I will not bother putting a screenshot here.

Comment: This sounds like a complicated redstone mechanism. Have you tried using command blocks yet? Also, your 'ATM' isn't explained very well. Is it a button you press, or an item you put in a container? Either way, I think command blocks would make this easier for you.

Comment: The ATM outputs a card through hoppers (the user's debit card). Wheb it does that, it also outputs a redstone signal. That is the signal that i want to use for this system. I also want to keep this world coand block free as i've been able to build everything else without it. But thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

The images below show the device. It can be expanded *infinitely* (You will need to adjust the wiring a bit if you extend it beyond a certain point). Looking at the third picture, the output is the redstone block closest the the POV. When you input a signal into the system through on of the button shown in the first image (you can replace this with anything), it will move the restone block in the third image to that position and constantly output a signal until you either wait for the hopper clock to run and finish, or until you input another signal into the system at the identical input point. This prevents other signals from inputting into the device by locking the repeaters of the other inputs so no signal can pass through. It will unlock after the hopper clock is finished (a possible flaw as inputting a signal again that deactivates the main output signal does not deactivate the locking repeater*). If anyone can find a more compact/better solution, please share it. Note: This will not be the accepted answer as it is fairly bulky and the question asks for a small design.

*depends on how you use this device.

I've detailed a solution that worked best for myself in this [imgur album](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsRCO.jpg).

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please do not post link-only answers. If you have images, please upload them to `i.stack.imgur.com` instead of `i.imgur.com`. | Tip: You can upload links instead of images (technically, all it does is crawl to the image and uploads a copy of that image to StackExchange)

Comment: @aytimothy Thanks for the tip. Sorry that it happened. I wrote the answer in a short time as I had to leave my house so I did not have time to fix that issue.

Comment: @aytimothy I use mostly i.stack.imgur but sometimes it doesn't work. (may be a bug in my system ?) so i had to upload to i.imgur . Is it okay?

Comment: Woah... You're 2 month late @Fennekin :P